# Moment of force acting at a point about other point

Tags: vectors, moment-problem

$F=4i-2j$ acts at a point $A=(2,5)$ then the perpendicular distance between $B=(10,3)$ and line of action if the force $F=..$? 
I found this kind of questions disturbing I don't know if I should start with $F x(A-B)$  or $F x (B-A)$ then finding the $P$. Distance. 
Can anyone explain the answer? With telling me a good method to solve the questions of this lesson. :) my exams are after 8 months and I still have other loads. 
Answer is: $\frac {15}{5}\sqrt{5}$

Comment: I am getting the answer as $4/\sqrt{5}$. Can you explain how it is wrong?

Comment: @samjoe i drew the lines and solved it using $M_o=\vec r$x $\vec F$

Comment: You said you want perpendicular distance? and moment is coming same as Peter found in his answer!

Answer (score 1):

By line of action, they probably mean line passing through $A(2,5)$ in direction of $\vec{F} = <4,-2>$.

So line of action can be written both in vector form or cartesian form. Going the cartesian way, the line is:

$$y-5 = -\frac{1}{2}(x-2)\\
x+2y-12 = 0$$

Perpendicular distance from $B(10,3)$ can be found using [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

$$\dfrac{10+6-12}{\sqrt{5}} \\= \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Cross product: $\vec M= \vec r × \vec F$.

This problem:

Let  $\vec a$  be the vector pointing from $ (0,0) $ to $ A$:

$\vec a = (2,5)$.

Let $ \vec b$ be the vector pointing from $ (0,0)$ to $B.$

$\vec b = (10,3)$

1) Force is acting at $A(2,5)$

2) $\vec F = (4,-2)$.

2) Take moment $\vec M$ about $B(10,3)$.

Vector pointing  from $B$ to $A$,

foot point $B$, head $A:$

$\vec a - \vec b = (-8,2)$.

$\vec M =  (-8,2,0)×(4,-2,0) = 8\hat{k}.$

Length of $ \vec M$ is $8$ pointing

in the $z$- direction.

Check: $ |\vec F|$ • perpendicular  distance from $B$ to line of action of force:

$|\vec M |$ = $|\vec F|$ • perpendicular distance $=$

$\sqrt{20} \dfrac{4}{√5} = 8.$

Used: Samjoe's distance.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: It is so confusing I cant understand and I solved it wrong

Comment: @Catfish Peter has solved correctly, and using two methods! What difficulty do you face?

Comment: @samjoe I totally ignored the rule! I used Mo= F x r!

Comment: I have studied that perpendicular difference = $||M_o||÷||\vec F||$

Comment: Catfish.Look up a few solved problems in your Mechanics textbook, or perhaps check with Shaum's Outline Physics in your library.Where specifically are you stuck ?

Comment: I have solved it now. It was lack of studying. My mechanics text book contains 9 examples and all of them are so easy.

Comment: Catfish. Very good, keep going, this problem  certainly was no reason to despair.